# Navigating JSON objects in a generic way in Haskell

Tags: python, json, haskell, casting, aeson

My goal is to write a program in Haskell that takes the name of a json file and interprets the rest of the arguments as a path to navigate that json file by and print the value navigated to. The problem is because JSON can contain multiple value types, I don't know how to make Haskell's type system understand what I want. Here is the Haskell code with the "navigate" function I'm not able to implement correctly:

```
import qualified Data.Aeson as A
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BSL
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import System.Environment

parse :: String -> A.Value
parse = fromJust . A.decode . BSL.pack

isInteger xs = case reads xs :: [(Integer, String)] of
    [(_, "")] -> True
    _ -> False

navigate :: A.Value -> String -> String
navigate value [] = value
navigate value [x:xs]
    | isInteger x = ??? -- value is an array, get the xth element of it.
    | otherwise = ??? -- value is an map, x is a key in it.

main :: IO ()
main = do
     [filename:path] <- getArgs
     contents <- readFile filename
     let d = parse contents
     putStrLn (show (navigate d path))
```

For reference, here is how the same program would have been written in Python:

```
from json import load
from sys import argv    
def navigate(obj, path):
    if not path:
        return obj
    head, tail = path[0], path[1:]
    return navigate(obj[int(head) if head.isdigit() else head], tail)    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fname, path = argv[1], argv[2:]
    obj = load(open(fname))
    print navigate(obj, path)
```

The program would be run like this:

```
$ cat data.json
{"foo" : [[1, 2, 3, {"bar" : "barf"}]]} 
$ python showjson.py data.json foo 0 3 bar
barf
```

Comment: Parse each argument with the JSON parse and write a function that indexes into a JSON value with another JSON value, and combine those the way you did in Python.

Comment: Note that when pattern matching cons cells (`x:xs`), you must use `(x:xs)` (the parenthesis are just for grouping, rather than special syntax). `[x:xs]` matches a list containing a single list, with `x` the head and `xs` the tail of the inner list, e.g. `[[1,2,3]]` => `x = 1, xs = [2,3]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply pattern match on the constructors of `A.Value` in order to figure out what kind of JSON object you are dealing with:

```
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as M
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Text as T

-- ... rest of the code more or less as before ...

navigate :: A.Value -> [String] -> BSL.ByteString
navigate value        []       = A.encode value
navigate (A.Array vs) (x : xs) = navigate (vs V.! read   x) xs
navigate (A.Object o) (x : xs) = navigate (o  M.! T.pack x) xs
```

Note that the definition of `A.Value` is as follows:

```
data Value
  = Object !(HashMap Text Value)
  | Array  !(Vector Value)
  | ...  -- other constructors
```

The code for `navigate` is thus making use of the lookup function (called `!` in both cases) on vectors and hash maps. The function `read` is used to interpret a command line argument as a number if needed (and will fail horribly if it isn't), whereas `T.pack` is reinterpreting the string as a value of type `Text`.